# Who was the Blue Bunny in the Grand Magic Games?

Tags: fairy-tail

Who was that blue bunny that was one of the 5 chosen one to be at the Grand Magic Games? I don't really understand.

Comment: you mean [Nichiya](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Nichiya)?

Answer (score 3):

Nichiya, shown here. 
[image]
Grand Magic Games Arc - 
Nichiya, now as a member of Blue Pegasus and wearing a rabbit costume, successfully passes the Preliminary Event with his team in 5th place, as seen when his team is announced in the first day of the Grand Magic Games of X791. When the teams meet each other, Lucy Heartfilia is the first to notice him and asks herself if he is actually human. At the start of the first event, Eve announces that he will be the one to compete for Blue Pegasus, and Nichiya, along with the other team members, supports his decision. Eve manages to get 4th place for Pegasus, and the Games proceed to the battle portion, starting with Lucy Heartfilia vs. Flare Corona. Despite the high tension of the audience during the battle, Nichiya is seen toasting a glass with Ichiya. The next battle is between Ren Akatsuki and Araña Webb, a fight that makes Natsu, Erza and Elfman wonder about Pegasus' strength, as they are intrigued by Nichiya in his rabbit costume.

[image]
[image]
[image]

> From: http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Nichiya